# Explain the algorithm and check whether the number is a prime number or not?

Tags: c

I understand only the code, but not its core concept. Can anyone explain the flowchart and algorithm?

Why do we use `i <= n/2` in this code? Is there any way to use `i <= n`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    int n, i, flag = 0;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {

        // condition for non-prime
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        printf("1 is neither prime nor composite.");
    }
    else {
        if (flag == 0)
            printf("%d is a prime number.", n);
        else
            printf("%d is not a prime number.", n);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose n is composite. Then n=ab for some integers a,b>1. Your first loop checks if a or b is an integer in the range [2, n/2]. If that loop never finds a factorization like that, it must be that one of the factors (if it exists) is greater than n/2. If it is greater than n/2, the other factor must be less than 2. The only such factorization is n=1n, in which case n is in fact a prime. Thus it suffices to check only factors up to n/2.

PS: I deliberately don't specify what I mean when n is odd. That's left as an exercise for you to fill in.

PPS: You can easily do a lot better than stopping at n/2. Hint: What happens when both factors are the same?

Comment: _You can easily do a lot better than stopping at n/2_ Nicely put. For the benefit of other, future readers: using `square-root` of `n` may reduce the number of iterations (in comparison to `n / 2`).

Answer (score -1):

In the code you are using `i <= n / 2` because for any numbers, you can't divide itself by another number greater than its half.

Let's take 29 for example (and use int, so not floating part).

```
29 / 2 = 14
29 / 3 = 9
29 / 4 = 7
29 / 5 = 5
...
29 / 14 = 2
29 / 15 = 1
29 / 16 = 1
...
```

Here, you see that after 14 (the half of 29), all the results are `1`.

If you wish to, you can even use this formula `n > i * i`. Let me explain with this example. Here, we should stop at `i = 5` because `29 < 6 * 6`

```
29 / 2 = 14
29 / 3 = 9
29 / 4 = 7
29 / 5 = 5
===== END HERE (but let's continue to see what happens) =====
29 / 6 = 4
29 / 7 = 4
29 / 8 = 3
...
```

You can see that after `5`, the results become smaller than the `index`, so you are just recalculating something that you have already calculated. It avoids timeouts on big numbers.